# How to restrict keypad characters to only numbers (editField in bada)

Tags: bada

I have an EditField in which the user ONLY can enter numeric characters but I don't know how to only show a numeric keypad instead of the deafault bloated keypad.

It would simplify the input (and remove the need of data validation)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look at the dedicated [forum](http://forums.badadev.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1123) here for Bada developers? You should register there and make use of the resources they have including the answer for you... :) *fellow bada programmer*